# Azure DevOps API work with releases states

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to get releases, which state is only 
[in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77z1Q.jpg), but when I send request `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={definitionId}&api-version=5.1` to get all releases and see, which field is responsible for release state I see, that all releases have status **active**.

I thought I must use `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={definitionId}&`**statusFilter=active**`&api-version=5.1`, but that is wrong way for my target task.

What should I use? Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're looking at the wrong API. You need to use the [deployments API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and specify [`deploymentStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#deploymentstatus) for querying the status of deployments.

The API you're using queries the overall status of a given release, not the individual stages. The JSON returned *contains* information about the stages, but you can't filter the stages based on their current status with that API.